# condensate line

Tags: pump, clog, condensate

2nd floor condo unit sharing condensate line with 1st floor.

1st floor installed condensate pump now my condensate safety continuously goes off as there is water by the safety.

We have had the condensate line cleaned numerous times (within days of each cleaning). One time it was cleaned 8am in the morning and my safety went off at midnight same day with visible water in the condensate line by a/c unit. When plumber returned there was less than a cup of water taken out and no debris.

I'm thinking the pump from the first floor is causing a bubble as there was very little water that came out but enough that it trips the safety. Seems the water is in the immediate run about the of the line by the safety.

I've lived there 16 years and did not have any problems until this pump was installed in the downstairs unit.

Coincidence or could it be the pump?

Comment: Seems like moving to an "unshared" line might be the straightforward cure, here.

Comment: Ruskes, Instead of gravity taking the condensate through the line, a pump is installed and pushes the condensate water through the line. Pumps have 1/2  gallon tanks and up. When pump tank fills, pump turns on and pushes the water through the line.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: Do you have a humidifier running, or where does the water comes from, it is not summer.

Comment: Ruskes, the condo is in Florida, A/c is  on. The water comes from a/c unit into the condensate line.

Comment: What do you mean by "sharing a condensate line"? How are they connected? I think both lines should empty into a reservoir tank and the pump should empty the tank when it fills up.

Comment: It sounds like those lines need a vent.

Comment: It's summer in some parts of the world...

Answer (score 1):

So I'm inferring that the lower condo is pumping INTO the same line you drain through, and in doing so, is pumping up your drain line. *This is not especially clear in the question as worded. Initially I thought the two condensates joined, and then there was an added pump, but that didn't seem to fit the problem.*

Other than my first suggestion in comments to "unshare" your line, the next thing that comes to mind is to put in a check valve, so your water can flow down, but their water can't flow up. Or, make the line after the point they join larger.

Answer (score 0):

If the pump is fitted before the 2 lines merge it is possible that when the downstairs unit's pump activates it pushes the water to drain outside, however it also pushes air in your line back toward your AC unit creating enough pressure to lift the drain float and disallow any condensation from running down your line. The result is disruption of your AC unit.
You may need to have a "T" fitted to your drain line directly after the safety switch to act as a vent preventing any pressure backing to your safety switch.

In any event, Fla. condo law allows that this should be the responsibility of your downstairs neighbor.